# Save file that doesn't get deleted at unistall

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to save a file on a Windows Phone 8 system that doesn't get deleted at unistall.

The file contains data that I whould like to restore if the app gets reinstalled.

In my research I found that I can't write to a file outside my Isolated Storage. is there a way to do this on Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way to do this is using a web storage method (skydrive, mobile services, azure...) to upload the data and, when the user logs again in the app restore from the web that info if not present locally...

Comment: I was afraid that is the case.